# zoom on picture in javascript after JS execute pic change

Tags: javascript

I have an image and a function to zoom in on mouse over. This works well.

I have a second picture (a thumbnail). If I click on the thumbnail, I have a JS function to change the first image, but in that case, the zoom in mouse over doesn't work, it shows me the original zoom.

my HTML:

```
<img src="small_1.jpg" border="0" id="bigImg"  data-zoom-image="big_1.jpg"><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showLarge('image_2.jpg')"><img src="small_image_2.jpg"></a>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function showLarge(path)
{
  var full_path = path;
  var full_path_large = 'large/'+path;
  document.getElementById("bigImg").src = full_path;
  document.getElementById("bigImg").setAttribute("data-zoom-image",full_path_large);
}

$('#bigImg').elevateZoom({
zoomType: "inner",
cursor: "crosshair",
zoomWindowFadeIn: 500,
zoomWindowFadeOut: 750
  });
```

Both functions work individually, but the zoom doesn't work after the showLarge(path) is executed.

Any thoughts... thanks

Comment: maybe you could also call `elevateZoom` inside `showLarge`

Comment: just tried... same result... the original picture big_1.jpg loads in the zooms over the second pic.

Comment: it also can't be inside show large, because it needs to work on page load on the first image and not exclusively when the showLarge() is called